# Remove duplicate Open Graph Image Meta Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

I´m running a website using Yoast SEO and from unknown reasons the images of my posts are not shown if I share the links on social media. I found the following post which recommends to replace "***og:image***" by "***og:image:secure_url***", since the image is located on an https url.

[how to fix facebook open graph images...](https://toodlepip.co.uk/2017/06/27/how-to-fix-facebook-opengraph-images-on-secure-sites-with-wordpress/)

So I added the following code to my functions.php file:

(I deleted some lines which create an additional metatag for og:image with an http url since I do not need that.)

```
function check_ssl_facebook_opengraph_image($image) { 
    $og = "og:image";
    if (preg_match('/^https/', $image)) {
        echo '<meta property="'. $og .             ':secure_url" content="'. $image . '" />' . "\n";
 }
}
// Hook into the Yoast plugin's hooks for handling the OG image
add_action('wpseo_opengraph_image', 'check_ssl_facebook_opengraph_image');
```

Unfortuntaly the code doesn´t replace the line in my wp-theme but adds a new line. As a result the post does include ***og:image*** and ***og:image:secure_url*** metatags with the same url.

I want to delete ***og:image*** from my post now since the image is still not visible if I post the link to social media. Perhaps it will be visible if only ***og:image:secure_url*** is present in my post.

I´m an absolute beginner with php. Can someone tell me how to delete the unneccessary ***og:image*** metatag after the secure_url string has been added?

Thanks in advance
Marc

Comment: `After some swearing and a fair bit of Googleage, it turns out that Facebook doesn’t play nicely when an image is served up via https but is specified using the og:image tag.` is wrong. `og:image` has no issue with the https protocol. I suspect your issue is elsewhere, and that whole tutorial is not worth the time reading. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111081/does-facebook-need-both-ogimage-and-ogimagesecure-url-for-https-only-site

Comment: Many thanks... I share your assumption that the issue is elsewhere since I can see posts from others who use og:image only and in combination with an https link.

Comment: @user3783243 What I read in the tutorial you shared and in other sources makes me guess that perhaps a combination of og:image with http link and og:image:secure_url with https link might bring success. Does someone know how to adapt the code to get this result?